# PulseAudio and Python3

Tags: python, pulseaudio, application-development

Accessing PulseAudio with Python2 is a bit tricky, but it works with the help of ctypes. The problem is that the same code fails to work with Python3. Apparently something was changed in ctypes, but I can't figure out what exactly.

Here's the sample code, which will list all the source devices. It works in Python2, but segfaults horribly in Python3.

```
# PulseAudio Source list:

import time
from ctypes import *
PA = CDLL('libpulse.so.0')
PA_CONTEXT_UNCONNECTED = 0
PA_CONTEXT_CONNECTING = 1
PA_CONTEXT_AUTHORIZING = 2
PA_CONTEXT_SETTING_NAME = 3
PA_CONTEXT_READY = 4
PA_CONTEXT_FAILED = 5
PA_CONTEXT_TERMINATED = 6
PA_OPERATION_RUNNING = 0
PA_OPERATION_DONE = 1
PA_OPERATION_CANCELLED = 2
STRING = c_char_p
size_t = c_ulong
uint32_t = c_uint32
uint8_t = c_uint8
class pa_mainloop_api(Structure):
    pass
class pa_threaded_mainloop(Structure):
    pass
pa_threaded_mainloop._fields_ = []
pa_threaded_mainloop_new = PA.pa_threaded_mainloop_new
pa_threaded_mainloop_new.restype = POINTER(pa_threaded_mainloop)
pa_threaded_mainloop_new.argtypes = []
pa_threaded_mainloop_free = PA.pa_threaded_mainloop_free
pa_threaded_mainloop_free.restype = None
pa_threaded_mainloop_free.argtypes = [POINTER(pa_threaded_mainloop)]
pa_threaded_mainloop_start = PA.pa_threaded_mainloop_start
pa_threaded_mainloop_start.restype = c_int
pa_threaded_mainloop_start.argtypes = [POINTER(pa_threaded_mainloop)]
pa_threaded_mainloop_stop = PA.pa_threaded_mainloop_stop
pa_threaded_mainloop_stop.restype = None
pa_threaded_mainloop_stop.argtypes = [POINTER(pa_threaded_mainloop)]
pa_threaded_mainloop_get_api = PA.pa_threaded_mainloop_get_api
pa_threaded_mainloop_get_api.restype = POINTER(pa_mainloop_api)
pa_threaded_mainloop_get_api.argtypes = [POINTER(pa_threaded_mainloop)]
class pa_context(Structure):
    pass
pa_context._fields_ = []
class pa_spawn_api(Structure):
    pass
class pa_stream(Structure):
    pass
pa_stream._fields_ = []
class pa_operation(Structure):
        pass
class pa_source_info(Structure):
    pass
pa_source_info._fields_ = [
    ('name', STRING),
    ('index', uint32_t),
    ('description', STRING),
]
pa_context_flags = c_int
pa_context_flags_t = pa_context_flags
pa_context_state = c_int
pa_context_state_t = pa_context_state
pa_context_notify_cb_t = CFUNCTYPE(None, POINTER(pa_context), c_void_p)
pa_context_success_cb_t = CFUNCTYPE(None, POINTER(pa_context), c_int, c_void_p)
pa_stream_success_cb_t = CFUNCTYPE(None, POINTER(pa_stream), c_int, c_void_p)
pa_stream_request_cb_t = CFUNCTYPE(None, POINTER(pa_stream), size_t, c_void_p)
pa_stream_notify_cb_t = CFUNCTYPE(None, POINTER(pa_stream), c_void_p)
pa_source_info_cb_t = CFUNCTYPE(None, POINTER(pa_context), POINTER(pa_source_info), c_int, c_void_p)

pa_context_new = PA.pa_context_new
pa_context_new.restype = POINTER(pa_context)
pa_context_new.argtypes = [POINTER(pa_mainloop_api), STRING]
pa_context_connect = PA.pa_context_connect
pa_context_connect.restype = c_int
pa_context_connect.argtypes = [POINTER(pa_context), STRING, pa_context_flags_t, POINTER(pa_spawn_api)]
pa_context_set_state_callback = PA.pa_context_set_state_callback
pa_context_set_state_callback.restype = None
pa_context_set_state_callback.argtypes = [POINTER(pa_context), pa_context_notify_cb_t, c_void_p]
pa_context_get_state = PA.pa_context_get_state
pa_context_get_state.restype = pa_context_state_t
pa_context_get_state.argtypes = [POINTER(pa_context)]
pa_stream_set_state_callback = PA.pa_stream_set_state_callback
pa_stream_set_state_callback.restype = None
pa_stream_set_state_callback.argtypes = [POINTER(pa_stream), pa_stream_notify_cb_t, c_void_p]

pa_context_get_source_info_list = PA.pa_context_get_source_info_list
pa_context_get_source_info_list.restype = POINTER(pa_operation)
pa_context_get_source_info_list.argtypes = [POINTER(pa_context), pa_source_info_cb_t, c_void_p]

def pa_state_cb(context, userdata):
    global pa_state
    state = pa_context_get_state(context)
    if state in [PA_CONTEXT_UNCONNECTED, PA_CONTEXT_CONNECTING, PA_CONTEXT_AUTHORIZING,
        PA_CONTEXT_SETTING_NAME]:
        pa_state = 0
    elif state == PA_CONTEXT_FAILED:
        pa_state = 2
    elif state == PA_CONTEXT_READY:
        pa_state = 1
    return  0

def pa_sourcelist_cb(context, source_info, eol, userdata):
    if eol==0:
        print("IDX:", source_info.contents.index, " ", source_info.contents.name, "--", source_info.contents.description)
    return  0

pa_ml = pa_threaded_mainloop_new()
pa_mlapi = pa_threaded_mainloop_get_api(pa_ml)

pa_ctx = pa_context_new(pa_mlapi, b"kazam-pulse")

error = -1
pa_state = 0
if pa_context_connect(pa_ctx, None, 0, None)!=0:
    print("cannot connect..")
    sys.exit(1)

pa_context_set_state_callback(pa_ctx, pa_context_notify_cb_t(pa_state_cb), None)
ret = pa_threaded_mainloop_start(pa_ml)

ctc = pa_context_get_state(pa_ctx)

time.sleep(1)
pa_context_get_source_info_list(pa_ctx, pa_source_info_cb_t(pa_sourcelist_cb), None);
time.sleep(1)
```

And here's the backtrace:

```
#0  0x00007ffff7e11fc1 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007ffff5e82d27 in pa_context_set_state (st=PA_CONTEXT_AUTHORIZING, c=0xae7d40) at pulse/context.c:291
#2  pa_context_set_state (c=0xae7d40, st=PA_CONTEXT_AUTHORIZING) at pulse/context.c:279
#3  0x00007ffff5e85691 in setup_context (io=0x7fffe8000910, c=0xae7d40) at pulse/context.c:561
#4  on_connection (client=<optimized out>, io=0x7fffe8000910, userdata=0xae7d40) at pulse/context.c:890
#5  0x00007ffff5a440e6 in do_call (c=0x9976c0) at pulsecore/socket-client.c:161
#6  0x00007ffff5e96ba7 in dispatch_defer (m=0x9ce180) at pulse/mainloop.c:704
#7  pa_mainloop_dispatch (m=0x9ce180) at pulse/mainloop.c:920
#8  0x00007ffff5e96de5 in pa_mainloop_iterate (m=0x9ce180, block=<optimized out>, retval=0x0) at pulse/mainloop.c:960
#9  0x00007ffff5e96e90 in pa_mainloop_run (m=0x9ce180, retval=0x0) at pulse/mainloop.c:975
#10 0x00007ffff5ea530f in thread (userdata=0x9a64a0) at pulse/thread-mainloop.c:88
#11 0x00007ffff5a4ed18 in internal_thread_func (userdata=0xa66840) at pulsecore/thread-posix.c:83
#12 0x00007ffff7bc4e9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#13 0x00007ffff65844bd in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#14 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Comment: Works for me here with Python 2.7 and 3.2. Since you've got a backtrace, might be interesting to go one step up the stack ('up' in gdb) and see what's actually going wrong ('list' to see where the code is at the time).

Comment: The code works for you? This probably means that something is wrong with my local installation. Can you tell me which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I tried this on a fresh ubuntu 12.04 install with the python3.2-minimal package and I get a segfault in python3.2mu...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a follow up. This problem was resolved. Using Python 3.2.3 in Precise Pangolin the posted code works as expected.